# Backing-up Linux server's 700GB data comprising mainly of files less than 10KB

Tags: linux, centos, backup, rsync, offsite-backup

What would you recommend as backup for the following scenario?

I have a CentOS 7 Linux server, with about 700GB data, comprising mainly of files less than 10KB.
The backup media needs eventually to go off-site.
When I tried to get an estimate of the time it would take, an rsync of the data took more than a week over Gigabit Ethernet (rsync reports average speeds of 40MB/s).

Comment: At 40 MB/sec that should take about six hours, not a week. Something is definitely wrong at one end or the other. Or that's not actually the average speed.

Comment: Also you should take a look at https://serverfault.com/q/365103/126632

Comment: @MichaelHampton probably that speed is for consecutive write/read.

Comment: @boardrider Do you have space on the server to compress the data first before downloading?

Comment: No, I don't @AvivLo